# Set up $\iint_S(x \mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j})\cdot d\mathbf{A}$ where $S$ is the surface of the given torus

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, stokes-theorem

Consider the circle in the $xz$-plane with center at $x = 5$, $z = 0$ and
radius $3$. If $S$ is the surface  generated by rotating the circle around the $z$-axis.

I am asked to orient S with unit normal vectors pointing away from the inside of the torus. Given this how can I set the integral for $$\iint_S(x \mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j})\cdot d\mathbf{A}$$

So far I have just gotten a parametrization of S

$S=((5+3\cos(t))(\cos (\theta),(5+3\cos(t))(\sin (\theta),3\sin (t))$

Comment: Your parametrization isn't quite right. The last term should be $3\sin(t)$. ... Are you allowed to use Gauss's (Divergence) Theorem?

Comment: I guess I am, but I have not studied it

Comment: Well. OK, so use the formula you've been given to compute the surface integral once you have a parametrization.